# Get UITextFields(1st Class) and Switches (2nd Class) values from other Class at runtime

Tags: core-data, delegates, uitextfield, swift3, uiswitch

I want to get the values of 5 UITextFields from PropertiesViewController.swift and 8 switches from ConditionsViewController (Both classes are part of a TabController). I want to insert the values the user inputs into CoreData once the user clicks on saveMeter(). My issue is  when I try to access both Views from another Class where I have all the CRUD actions. When I hit the save button on Properties or ConditionsViewController the texts and switches values return nil even though I just input a value.

The class is named CRUDController and here is the must important Code:

class CRUDController: UIViewController {

var conditions : ConditionsViewController

var properties : PropertiesViewController

```
init(){
```

//I understand below I am creating a new instance and not the original

//but swift force me to init them and I dont know other way to do it.

// I have also tried referencing them like this:

//var conditions : ConditionsViewController var properties : PropertiesViewController

//from the function saveMeter but values from text are still null.

```
   conditions = ConditionsViewController()
    properties =  PropertiesViewController()

    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle:nil)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

func saveMeter() {

```
    //conditions.setConditions()
    //properties.setProperties()

        //creating empty meter
        let m1 = Meter(context: MOC)
```

//this is were I am setting the values for the Meter Object in Coredata

```
        //conditions values
        m1.newMeterCond1 = conditions.newMeterCond1Val
        m1.newMeterCond2 = conditions.newMeterCond2Val
        m1.newMeterCond3 = conditions.newMeterCond3Val
        m1.oldMeterCond1 = conditions.oldMeterCond1Val
        m1.oldMeterCond2 = conditions.oldMeterCond2Val
        m1.oldMeterCond3 = conditions.oldMeterCond3Val
        m1.oldMeterCond4 = conditions.oldMeterCond4Val
        m1.oldMeterCond5 = conditions.oldMeterCond5Val
        m1.cnc = conditions.CNCVal 

       //properties values                
       m1.outKW =  properties.OutKWFromTextField
        m1.outKWH = properties.OutKWHFromTextField
       m1.outKVARH = properties.OutKVARHFromTextField
       m1.multiplier = properties.multiplierFromTextField
       m1.newMeterNumber = properties.newMeterNumberFromTextField


        APPD.saveContext()

}
```

}

Here are the classes were I am getting the text fields and the switches:

class ConditionsViewController: UIViewController {

```
//variables to set

var newMeterCond1Val = Bool()
var newMeterCond2Val = Bool()
var newMeterCond3Val = Bool()
var oldMeterCond1Val = Bool()
var oldMeterCond2Val = Bool()
var oldMeterCond3Val = Bool()
var oldMeterCond4Val = Bool()
var oldMeterCond5Val = Bool()
var CNCVal = Bool()

@IBOutlet weak var oldMeterNumber: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var newMeterNumber: UILabel!
var oldMeterFromCell = String()
var newMeterFromTabChild = String()

//old meter conditions
@IBOutlet weak var oldMeterCond1: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var oldMeterCond2: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var oldMeterCond3: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var oldMeterCond4: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var oldMeterCond5: UISwitch!

//new meter conditions
@IBOutlet weak var newMeterCond1: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var newMeterCond2: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var newMeterCond3: UISwitch!


@IBOutlet weak var CNC: UISwitch!

@IBAction func saveMeter(_ sender: AnyObject) {

   //this is where I am calling the function from CRUDController
    CRUD.saveMeter()
}
```

}

class PropertiesViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

```
var oldMeterFromCell = String()

//variables to set
var OutKWHFromTextField = Float()
var OutKWFromTextField = Float()
var OutKVARHFromTextField = Float()
var newMeterNumberFromTextField = String()
var multiplierFromTextField = Float()

@IBOutlet weak var OldMeterLabel: UILabel!

//new meter properties
@IBOutlet weak var OutKWH: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var OutKW: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var OutKVARH: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var newMeterNumber: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var multiplier: UITextField!
```

}

I have tried initializing the UITextField and the Switches from each of their classes with init() and required init(), I have also tried using convenience init(), I have also initialize them with a custom set function. I have also created an instance to both classes on The  CRUDController Class but the text values are still coming back nil when I hit the save button. I cannot use a segue because I have 2 views and even if I could I don't want to. I need to have access to the originals PropertiesController and ConditionsController from the CRUDController class and I don't know how to do it as I am very confused with the concept of delegation and how to make things work so I need CODE that solves the problem, NO CONCEPTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found that can solve this issue is to connect all the switches,UITextfields,actions,etc from the different Views in StoryBoard to one single class which have access to all of the elements. This way there is no need of instantiating one Class to access another.